# select query within a select query is possible

Tags: sql

```
SELECT account_id, maintenance_cost AS amount FROM community_details 
WHERE community_id = %s

SELECT amount, receipt_no FROM bill_payments WHERE bill_id = %s
```

can i merge these two queires

Comment: Tag should be SQL instead of python. Even though you might be using it in python, the subproblem is related to SQL or any other Query language

Comment: I've removed the [tag:python] tag completely, since this is purely a SQL question only, regardless of whether Python is being used, its not at all relevant to the question.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you want to do.  "combine" is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can by using `UNION`

```
SELECT account_id, maintenance_cost AS amount FROM community_details 
WHERE community_id = %s

UNION

SELECT amount, receipt_no FROM bill_payments WHERE bill_id = %s
```

e.g:

```
CREATE TABLE rs (`Location` VARCHAR(5), `Region` VARCHAR(5), `Year` VARCHAR(5), `Sales` INTEGER);

INSERT INTO rs (`Location`, `Region`, `Year`, 'Sales') VALUES
  ('SS1', 'R1', '2019', 100),
  ('SS2', 'R1', '2019', 200),
  ('SS3', 'R2', '2019', 300),
  ('SS1', 'R1', '2020', 400),
  ('SS2', 'R1', '2020', 500),
  ('SS3', 'R2', '2020', 600);
```

---

```
with res as (select * from rs
where Year='2020')

select Location as Location , sum(sales) as "Sales(2020)" from res
group by Location
UNION
select Region, sum(sales) from res
group by region
UNION
select "Total", sum(sales) from res
```

---

Comment: UNION ALL _returns_ duplicates, UNION _removes_ duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh: Yes I have mentioned that only.  `UNION --> this will not allow duplicates.` i.e duplicates will get removed.

Comment: aah I got it. I mean while showing them duplicates will not be there. Thanks for pointing this out :)